# Azure APIM and Hybrid Connections

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, hybrid-cloud

I am trying to access On-Prem APIs Via Azure APIM. I can access the On-Prem API if I do a VNET and VPN tunnel however, its not an ideal solution for the purpose.
I am trying to get Hybrid Connections (port bridge) to work as the same way. 
I have created a Hybrid Connection and installed Hybrid Connection Manager On-Prem and the hybrid connection link itself is connected.

Now, How do i make my APIM to use this hybrid Relay? Some work needs to be done in policies I believe.

Comment: My understanding is that Hybrid Connection has been designed to work with App Service. I do not believe there is a way for APIM to use it directly.  In what way are VNET and VPN not an ideal solution for your scenario?

Comment: Mainly on deployment All clients will not be happy to open a VPN to their On-Prem. Also we need to involve Networking teams during deployment cost factor for man hours along those line

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to create an Azure API App that proxies the request via a hybrid connection to the on-prem API.  Then use API Management to talk to the Azure API App.

Answer (score 1):

APIM dosen't support Hybrid Relay. The work around is to use WCF relay instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hybrid Connection and attach it to web service. Install Hybrid Connection Manager and install it on your on-premise server. After you wire the hybrid connection manager to the web service, use the web.config to set up URL Re-writes or Application Request Routing to connect to the local server.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are trying to use the VPN option because you do not want to expose your backend service on-prem to the cloud. How about running the api gateway on-premise and do the rest of the api management in the cloud (a hybrid solution). If so, this is available in the WSO2 API Cloud today. Your api calls will hit the gateway in your datacenter which will avoid using any VPNs to connect to the backend. Have a look at
https://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/going-hybrid-on-premises-api-gateways/

Comment: I think this is not a place to market about a product

Comment: @IshamMohamed I don't agree with you. I have given relevant and valuable information to get KEL_Syd 's scenario working (without using Azure stuff)